# Can't we make folder programatically in external storage of Android 'R' i.e. android 11 using flutter (OS Error: Operation not permitted, errno = 1)

Tags: android, flutter, android-manifest, file-permissions

I'm downloading 1 image from URL

```
   await dio.download(url, saveFile.path,
            onReceiveProgress: (value1, value2) {
          setState(() {
            progress = value1 / value2;
            print(progress);
          });
        });
```

**This Works fine in Android 10 but not working in Android 11 Why ?**

This is my exception:-
FileSystemException: Creation failed, path = '/storage/emulated/0/4k unique wallpapers' (OS Error: Operation not permitted, errno = 1)

Though I had called this code in Manifest...

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

<application
    android:preserveLegacyExternalStorage="true"
    android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
</application>
```

Comment: You did not tell what you want to do and there is no code that does anything. Please write a normall post.

Comment: Your code does not show which folder it tries to create. Or where. Please write a normal post.

Comment: Do you find the solution yet?

Answer (score 0):

I came here via the [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/Baseflow/flutter-permission-handler/issues/606) on the Permission Handler plugin. It worked on Android 10, but not on Android 11 you said. Have you tried using the `manageExternalStorage` permission of the plugin you're using? In the manifest you should add this:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

And of course you need to `request()` the permission.

Please read the documentation of the manage external storage, because Google needs to approve the usage of the manageExternalStorage. Let me know if this fixed your problem!

Comment: That issue was raised by me. I had added all permissions.